# How to center HTML content

Tags: html, css

I have an html page with some inline CSS. The content is on the left side.

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <p style="font-size:14px">Insurance Certificate</p>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:12px">Mobile Phones, Tablets & Laptops Insurance Cover</p>
    <hr align="left" width="75%">
</div>
<div style="width:50%; text-align:left; background-color : #EAEBEC ">
    <p style=""><b>Master Policy Number</b>: 260200/64/14/9500000018</p>
    <p style=""><b>Pack Reference No</b>:</p>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-size:10px; text-align:justify; width:50%">This is to certify that the device as described below in the schedule is covered under Special Contingency Policy issued by National Insurance Co. Ltd. (herein after called Insurer), subject to the terms, conditions, and exclusions as briefly
            contained overleaf.</td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; text-align: right; ">Name of the Insured in full:</td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; "> RICHARD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b> &nbsp;Address for communication:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; "> 29 RAPHAELS HOUSE 5TH STREET,
            <br /> ANDAL NAGAR ALAPAKKAM,
            <br />CHENNAI, 600116</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Contact Number :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">9840619103</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b> Email ID :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">richard9969@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Device Brand & Model:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">iPhone 5s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Device Purchase Date :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">30-12-2015 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>IMEI / Serial No:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">352087071244199</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Sum Insured:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">25500.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Invoice No / Certification No:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMV-S/5138/15/IMV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Insurance Plans:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">All Risk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Coverage Start Date & Time</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">30-12-2015, 13:29:04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Coverage End Date</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">29-12-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Store Code</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Store Name</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMAGINE-VADAPALANI</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <p>
        Any communication in respect to this policy may be sent to the facilitator mentioned below.
        <br />
        <b>Edelweiss Insurance Brokers Limited</b>
        <br />Unit No.102, 10th Floor, Sakhar Bhavan, 230 Nariman Point, Mumbai 400021 Tel 22-42639603/
        <br /> 18605005200 <b>Business Hours</b> Monday to Friday 10 am to 6 pm <b>eMail</b> ample.claims@edelweissfin.com

    </p>
</div>
```

I am not getting how to center the content.

Comment: Try     <body style="margin:0 auto;">

Comment: no its not reflecting

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ymaate4c/1/ 

I used here Your code put inside a DIV tag with style.

Comment: ya its working, thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<body > 
    <div id="container" style="width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

    <!-- Your HTML code -->

    </div>
</body>
```

Hope it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the `table` in a `div` and put the style as `margin: 0 auto;` for that div.

Something like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simple, just ***wrap*** all the contents in a `div` and position it.

Just insert the following line right after the beginning of the `<body>` tag,

```
<div style="top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;margin:auto;">
```

and right before the closing of `</body>` tag, include a `</div>` tag and that would center all the content both vertically and horizontally.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put `<center>` before `<div>` and close it after closing div.
HTML:

```
    <center>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <p style="font-size:14px">Insurance Certificate</p>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:12px">Mobile Phones, Tablets & Laptops Insurance Cover</p>
    <hr align="left" width="75%">
</div>
<div style="width:50%; text-align:left; background-color : #EAEBEC ">
    <p style=""><b>Master Policy Number</b>: 260200/64/14/9500000018</p>
    <p style=""><b>Pack Reference No</b>:</p>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-size:10px; text-align:justify; width:50%">This is to certify that the device as described below in the schedule is covered under Special Contingency Policy issued by National Insurance Co. Ltd. (herein after called Insurer), subject to the terms, conditions, and exclusions as briefly
            contained overleaf.</td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; text-align: right; ">Name of the Insured in full:</td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; "> RICHARD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b> &nbsp;Address for communication:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; "> 29 RAPHAELS HOUSE 5TH STREET,
            <br /> ANDAL NAGAR ALAPAKKAM,
            <br />CHENNAI, 600116</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Contact Number :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">9840619103</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b> Email ID :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">richard9969@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Device Brand & Model:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">iPhone 5s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Device Purchase Date :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">30-12-2015 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>IMEI / Serial No:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">352087071244199</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Sum Insured:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">25500.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Invoice No / Certification No:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMV-S/5138/15/IMV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Insurance Plans:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">All Risk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Coverage Start Date & Time</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">30-12-2015, 13:29:04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Coverage End Date</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">29-12-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Store Code</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Store Name</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMAGINE-VADAPALANI</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <p>
        Any communication in respect to this policy may be sent to the facilitator mentioned below.
        <br />
        <b>Edelweiss Insurance Brokers Limited</b>
        <br />Unit No.102, 10th Floor, Sakhar Bhavan, 230 Nariman Point, Mumbai 400021 Tel 22-42639603/
        <br /> 18605005200 <b>Business Hours</b> Monday to Friday 10 am to 6 pm <b>eMail</b> ample.claims@edelweissfin.com

    </p>
</div>
</center>
```

I've also created a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxbzfptj/

Answer (score 0):

You can put `align="center"` before closing the `<div>`, like this:

```
<div align="center">
    <p style="font-size:14px">Insurance Certificate</p>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:12px">Mobile Phones, Tablets & Laptops Insurance Cover</p>
    <hr align="left" width="75%">
</div>
<div style="width:50%; text-align:left; background-color : #EAEBEC ">
    <p style=""><b>Master Policy Number</b>: 260200/64/14/9500000018</p>
    <p style=""><b>Pack Reference No</b>:</p>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-size:10px; text-align:justify; width:50%">This is to certify that the device as described below in the schedule is covered under Special Contingency Policy issued by National Insurance Co. Ltd. (herein after called Insurer), subject to the terms, conditions, and exclusions as briefly
            contained overleaf.</td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; text-align: right; ">Name of the Insured in full:</td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; "> RICHARD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b> &nbsp;Address for communication:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; "> 29 RAPHAELS HOUSE 5TH STREET,
            <br /> ANDAL NAGAR ALAPAKKAM,
            <br />CHENNAI, 600116</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Contact Number :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">9840619103</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b> Email ID :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">richard9969@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Device Brand & Model:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">iPhone 5s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Device Purchase Date :</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">30-12-2015 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>IMEI / Serial No:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">352087071244199</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Sum Insured:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">25500.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Invoice No / Certification No:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMV-S/5138/15/IMV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; "><b>Insurance Plans:</b></td>
        <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">All Risk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Coverage Start Date & Time</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">30-12-2015, 13:29:04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Coverage End Date</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">29-12-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Store Code</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: right; ">Store Name</td>
        <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">IMAGINE-VADAPALANI</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <p>
        Any communication in respect to this policy may be sent to the facilitator mentioned below.
        <br />
        <b>Edelweiss Insurance Brokers Limited</b>
        <br />Unit No.102, 10th Floor, Sakhar Bhavan, 230 Nariman Point, Mumbai 400021 Tel 22-42639603/
        <br /> 18605005200 <b>Business Hours</b> Monday to Friday 10 am to 6 pm <b>eMail</b> ample.claims@edelweissfin.com

    </p>
</div>
```

I've also created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeaGwo) and a for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
  text-align : center;
  }
```